# Mousse de Canard, Mousse de Foie, Terrine de Campagne, expired by around 10 days

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, storage, mousse, packaging

[image: items]

I have here, Terrine de Campagne and Mousse de Canard with Expiry of Mar 16, this year.
Mousse de Foie expired Mar 22.
So all are expired and their packages have ballooned up.
I'm wondering if they are still safe to eat?

Comment: The 'ballooned up' usually gives it away. Don't even open them, the smell will haunt you for a while.

Comment: You might as well be asking if they would be safe to eat if they were an odd shade of green and smelled like death.

Answer (score 11):

I'm sorry to say that your three packages are no longer safe for consumption. Expiry dates are usually pretty conservative and food may still be good several days past them, but the concerning factor in your case is the ballooning of your packaging.

As various bacteria live their lives, they produce gas. A small amount of bacteria over a short amount a time will not be enough to produce enough gas to make any noticeable change to a packaging and is completely safe. However, the fact that your unopened factory-sealed packages have ballooned up points to a serious multiplication of said bacteria.

I recommend you throw away all three packages.

Answer (score 1):

Ballooned package = trashcan.

'nough said.